# Check if a pair of columns in a dataframe matches a pair of columns in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, pyspark

A solution in Pandas or PySpark is good either way, I am interested in the logic.

I have two dataframes:

```
df_1 = 

id_1   id_2   value
ABC    XYZ    AA+
ABA    XYY    null
ABD    YYZ    null
ABD    ZYZ    A+
ABB    XYY    AA-
ACC    XZY    A--
BBB    YYY    null

df_2 =

id_1   id_2   value
ABC    XYZ    AA+
ABA    XYY    CCC
ABD    YYZ    UNDEF
ABD    ZYZ    A-
ABB    XYY    AA-
```

**How do I check that for every pair of `id_1` and `id_2` in `df_2`, this pair exists in `df_1` and has the same `value`? I want to track the problematic rows where there isn't a match:**

```
expected_output = 

id_1   id_2   value   value_actual
ABA    XYY    null    CCC
ABD    YYZ    null    UNDEF
ABD    ZYZ    A+      A-
```

I overcomplicated myself because I initially wanted a result where I can check multiple attributes and did:

```
def matching_spark(df_1, df_2):
    
    df_1 = df_1.withColumn('index', row_number().over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy('id_1','id_2')))
    df_2 = df_2.withColumn('index', row_number().over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy('id_1','id_2')))

    s = df_1.unionByName(df_2).orderBy('id_1','id_2','index')
    s = s.withColumn('change',array('value'))
    s = s.withColumn('cols',split(lit('value'),'\,'))
    s= s.withColumn('change1',last('change').over(Window.partitionBy('index').orderBy('id_1','id_2'))).where(col('change')!=col('change1'))
    s = s.withColumn('change2', expr("transform(change,(c,i)->change[i]!=change1[i])")).withColumn('faulty_attr',expr('filter(cols,(x,j)->(change2[j]))')).drop('index','change','cols','change1' ,'change2')
    return s
```

But nothing is coming out and I believe there is a simple joining solution for the example I have above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`merge` and filter:

```
(df1.merge(df2, on=['id_1', 'id_2'], suffixes=(None, '_actual'))
    .query('value != value_actual')
)
```

output:

```
  id_1 id_2 value value_actual
1  ABA  XYY   NaN          CCC
2  ABD  YYZ   NaN        UNDEF
3  ABD  ZYZ    A+           A-
```